# How to set up an extended desktop on dual monitors in Kubuntu 9.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop, kubuntu

I'm using my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T60) and I have a secondary monitor (which has a different resolution than my laptop screen) connected by VGA. Kubuntu recognizes the monitor and it functions but my desktop is mirrored (i.e. an identical copy) across the dual monitors (which is useless to me). How can I extend my desktop across both monitors?

P.S. I searched Google but the solutions I found weren't standard; they were hardware specific and you had to manually change system files, etc. There must be an easier way.

Here is a snapshot of the settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**, see solution here: [extended display on Lenovo T60 (Intel 945GM series of chipset)](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-to-set-up-an-extended-desktop-on-dual-monitors-in-kubuntu-9.04-761716/)